# Apache Proxy Pass and Web Sockets

Tags: apache-2.2, proxypass, socket

I'm using Apache with the `mod_proxy` module to reverse proxy my Node.js application through to port 80, so that we can access it as an *internal* application.

I have a file in `sites-enabled` which contains this:

```
VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/internal/
    ServerName internal
    ServerAlias internal

    <Directory /var/www/internal/public/>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ProxyRequests off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyTimeout 1200
    LogLevel debug

    AllowEncodedSlashes on
</VirtualHost>
```

As I said, our application is written in Node.js and we're using [socket.io](http://socket.io) to make use of web-sockets, as our application also contains realtime elements to it. The problem is, `mod_proxy` doesn't seem to handle web sockets and we get errors when trying to use them:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://bloot/socket.io/1/websocket/nHtTh6ZwQjSXlmI7UMua' failed: Unexpected response code: 502
```

How can we fix this issue and keep sockets working, as the only way we can get it working currently is to access the site via `ip:port` which we don't want to do.

*Also, as a side question, how can I get `ErrorDocument` to work properly? Our error files are stored in `/var/www/internal/public/error/` but they seem to get put through the proxy too?*

Comment: Do you understand how web sockets work?

Comment: Briefly. I just installed HAProxy, set that up and everything seems to work now. Thanks to [this](http://blog.physalix.com/reverse-proxy-for-nodejs-in-production-with-apache2-haproxy-and-monit/).

Answer (score 1):

In Apache 2.2, web sockets are not supported by reverse proxy but I guess Apache 2.4 have. You have three options to solve this issue.

1) Either you upgrade to 2.4

2) You can use polling (xhr-polling) instead of web sockets. All you need to do is configure transport method in server side Node.js code like this.

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(PORT);

io.configure(function () {
  io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]);
});
```

This way socket.io will not attempt to figure out the best transport method. It will directly use xhr-polling which is simply Ajax based polling and works in every browser and web server without any issue.

3) If you still want to use web sockets, you can recompile Apache 2.2 with web socket support. Check this article for more detail on that:
http://blog.cafarelli.fr/post/2013/04/26/Backporting-Apache-support-for-websockets-reverse-proxy-%28aka-getting-GateOne-to-work-behind-Apache%29